# How can I create a 2D tensor with one element a sine and the other a cosine wave?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm doing

```
train_data = np.array([np.sin(time), np.cos(time)])
```

This gives me something with a shape of `(2, 4000)`. I think I need it to be `(4000, 2)`, so for each timestep, I can get the sin and cos.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you simply transpose it? `np.array(...).T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy transpose to switch the array around.

Try this:

```
train_data = np.array([np.sin(time), np.cos(time)]).T
```

Here's what I did to get (4000,2).

```
import numpy as np
time = np.arange(4000)
train_data = np.array([np.sin(time), np.cos(time)])
print (train_data.shape)
print (train_data.T.shape)
```

The output for this was:

```
(2, 4000)
(4000, 2)
```

Comment: Swtiching does not have the same effect of transposing.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it does.